# Is possible to create a launcher that open bash terminal with focus on a specific folder?

Tags: bash

As a title, or in other words is possible assign in bash launcher a custom .bashrc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `--title` argument to gnome-terminal, though it will likely get overwritten. You can also use `--working-directory` to specify a specific path that the new terminal is opened to. And finally, you can use the `--command` option to specify what command to run. Like so:

```
gnome-terminal --command "bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc-special"
```

Comment: Another option is `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'cd /whatever/path; exec bash'` which avoids the need for a separate bashrc. Yet another option, which applies specifically to gnome-terminal, is that if you open a gnome-terminal (the "usual" way) and hit Ctrl+Shift+N, a new terminal is opened, with the cwd set to the same as the current gnome-terminal's shell has.

Comment: @geirha Yes, but that is a very complicated way to just do gnome-terminal --working-directory /whatever/path. :)

Comment: aye, but it can be applied to most terminal emulators, e.g. with uxterm: `uxterm -e 'cd /whatever/path; exec bash'`. I agree with your answer. I merely intended to expand on it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer... little problem: have used the original gnome-terminal.desktop file for my launcher and have changed in this:TryExec=gnome-terminal --working-directory "~/Works"
Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory "~/Works" but don't work...where have to add the argument?

Comment: Update: If use Exec=gnome-terminal x bash -c 'cd ~/Works; exec bash' works.

Comment: @Angelbit You need to make a copy of gnome-terminal.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications/ as "works-terminal.desktop" or something. You should change the Name= (to "Terminal (~/Works)" or similar) and Exec= to include the new arguments. The TryExec= should not be changed.

Comment: @dobey yep, have tested the arguments on copy of the original gnome-terminal.desktop, if modify only Exec with --working-directory "~/Works" argument, terminal run but it focus on default ~ directory not ~/Works

Comment: @Angelbit, in the shell, `~` gets replaced with your home directory (or more correctly, the value of the HOME environment variable). The Exec=-line in a .desktop file is *not* interpreted by a shell, and does not replace `~` with the value of HOME. Variable expansions on the Exec=-line *are* honored though, so `Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory "$HOME/Works"` should work.

Comment: @geirha resolved, works only if pass '/home/myname/Works', with $Home/Works or ~/Works no. Thanks to all.

Comment: Oops, strike my last comment. I just tested. It doesn't expand variables either. So you'll need either the `-e|--command` or `-x|--execute` to launch a shell that does such expansions.